# Open Angular page with parameters

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to redirect to the page of a new application written in Angular and send data
Is it possible to transfer, for example, a token to the angular?

I tried to make a redirect to - http://localhost:4200/token/hrl4lhlhga - hrl4lhlhga <== token

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'token/:value',
    component: TestComponent,
  }
];
```

```
export class TestComponent {
  @Input() value?: string;
}
```

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes, withComponentInputBinding()),
```

But 'value' always undefined

**ADDED 18.03**

*main.ts*

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

*app.config.ts*

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes, withDebugTracing(), withComponentInputBinding()),
    provideAnimations(),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi()),
    importProvidersFrom(BrowserModule, ToastModule, InputTextModule, InputNumberModule, InputTextareaModule, MatCardModule, CommonModule, FormsModule, MenubarModule, DropdownModule, DragDropModule, FieldsetModule, CardModule, PanelModule, ButtonModule, FlexLayoutModule, TagModule, AccordionModule, ScrollPanelModule, TableModule),
    BackEndService, DialogService, MessageService, ApplicationService, 
  ]
}
```

I have added withDebugTracing and for http://localhost:4200/token/hrl4lhlhga now I get

```
ERROR Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'token/hrl4lhlhga'
```

The paths appear to have been loaded, but for some reason Angular cannot establish that such a path exists. Maybe something conflicts in my configuration or I described everything incorrectly

Comment: No issues with the above code .
Make sure you are not getting any other errors, check in the browser console.
And verify the place the token is generated , when accessing the link check whether it have valid value,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why this happened. One of my components had a **RouterTestingModule** imported (now deprecated). Therefore, all my routes were rewritten and cleaned up. I just removed this from the import and now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

in provideRouter you should inject routes not appRoutes

```
  bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes, withComponentInputBinding()),
```

Comment: I have everything right here. I wrote it wrong in the description here

Comment: can you show me the code where you redirect to that route